# Can't share socket session between express and socket.io

Tags: node.js, sockets, session, express

I'm trying to share an express-session with socket.io session but am not able to access the saved session variables from my express routes. I'm using [express-socket.io-session](https://github.com/oskosk/express-socket.io-session) to share the session. When I save data on the socket's "connection" event, and then trigger a route change, express seems unaware of the changed session data.

```
const path = require('path');

const app = require('express')();
const server = require('http').Server(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
const session = require('express-session')({
    secret: 'secret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true
});
var sharedsession = require('express-socket.io-session');

app.use(session);

io.use(sharedsession(session, {
    autoSave: true
}))

io.on('connection', (socket) => {

    socket.handshake.session.data = ['connection']
    console.log(socket.handshake.session);

    // First
    socket.on('login', data => {
        socket.handshake.session.data.push('login');
        console.log(socket.handshake.session);
    });
})

// Second
app.get('/route', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.session.data); // => undefined
})

app.get('/*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
})

server.listen(3000);
```

I've spent a lot of time troubleshooting with different configuration options with no success. The best way for me to demonstrate the problem by creating an extremely minimal example in a repo:
https://github.com/matt-mcdaniel/express-socket-test

Why can't I access the saved data from my socket connection in my express routes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing the .save() method when you are setting a value in session from socket io like this - 
socket.handshake.session.data = ['connection'];
socket.handshake.session.save();

This should work probably.